# set tool tip for each cell of a devexpress gridview

Tags: devexpress

how to set tool tip for each cell of a devexpress gridview in asp.net & c#.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the "OnHtmlDataCellPrepared" property of your grid, like this:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" 
    OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared">
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Then set the "title" attribute of the cells in your codebehind:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object  sender,  DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs  e)  
{
    e.Cell.Attributes.Add("title", "Your Tooltip");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as mhughes but in my case the gridView is dynamically created so I had to add the event handler after the fact.

_gridview.HtmlDataCellPrepared += new ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventHandler(_gridview_HtmlDataCellPrepared);

void _gridview_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CellValue != null)
         e.Cell.Attributes.Add("title", e.CellValue.ToString());
}